# entries in multiple dates in access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a access table that has quarterly pricing data starting from 20100131 and goes on as 20100430, 20100731.... 20170131, 20170430. For each pricing date, there are many loans. Some loans stay in the portfolio, some loans are removed and some added for each pricing period. I would like to find the list of loans that exist in all periods and see their price for each period. So i have the "Loan_Number" field and "Price_Date" field. I would like to find the Loan Numbers that exist in all price date points. I appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to work just a little with your homework before calling on us.

Answer (score 0):

Would have been nice to see some effort from you but I was intrigued with the challenge so here is what I accomplished.

1 - Need a dataset of all possible combinations of loan numbers and date values. So if you have a LoanNumbers table and a Periods table, create a Cartesian query called AllPairs:
`SELECT LoanNumbers.Loan_Number, Periods.Price_Date FROM LoanNumbers, Periods;`
If you don't have those tables, generate datasets with queries, assuming the data table has at least one record for every loan number and at least one record for every period:
`SELECT DISTINCT Table1.Price_Date FROM Table1;`
`SELECT DISTINCT Table1.Loan_Number FROM Table1;`

2 - Join AllPairs to data table for a 'find unmatched' query called LoanNoPeriod:
`SELECT AllPairs.Loan_Number, AllPairs.Price_Date, Table1.Loan_Number, Table1.Price_Date
FROM AllPairs LEFT JOIN Table1 ON (AllPairs.Price_Date = Table1.Price_Date) AND (AllPairs.Loan_Number = Table1.Loan_Number)
WHERE (((Table1.Price_Date) Is Null));`

3 - Final query:
`SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Loan_Number NOT IN (SELECT AllPairs.Loan_Number FROM LoanNoPeriod);`

Be aware these type of queries can perform very slowly and with very large datasets might not be practical.